# when I search about this code from MYSQL in entry show bug but when use select run good

Tags: python, mysql-connector

```py
def search_user():
        try:
            sqlcon = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="Eng100")
            cur = sqlcon.cursor()
            sql = "SELECT us_mobile, us_name,us_job,us_zone,us_email,us_tokenpass,us_newpass FROM Eng_user WHERE us_code = '1151'"
            # value = str(txt_code.get())
            cur.execute(sql)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            # print(rows)
            #====================
            for x in rows:
                us_mobile.set(x[1])
                us_name.set(x[2])
                us_job.set(x[3])
                us_zone.set(x[4])
                us_email.set(x[5])
                us_tokenpass.set(x[6])
                us_newpass.set(x[7])
                txt_datecreate.set_date(rows[7])
            #====================
            sqlcon.commit()
            sqlcon.close()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Management System Eng100", "-> Something Went Wrong PLease feedback developer")
```

OUTPUT: -

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\MAKKA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1884, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "d:\cmnkls\Python\eng100\main_eng100.py", line 1007, in search_user
> us_newpass.set(x[7]) IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: It's all in the error-message. index 7 of x does not exist. My guess is that you should start at index 0 and end at index 6 at newpass.

Answer (score 0):

Lists and tuples in Python are numbered from 0, not from 1.

```
for x in rows:
    us_mobile.set(x[0])
    us_name.set(x[1])
    us_job.set(x[2])
    us_zone.set(x[3])
    us_email.set(x[4])
    us_tokenpass.set(x[5])
    us_newpass.set(x[6])
```